# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object

Tags: android-studio

E  FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.myapplication, PID: 27689
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.myapplication/com.example.myapplication.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3815)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3977)
at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:109)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2374)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:233)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:344)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8248)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:589)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1071)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
at com.example.myapplication.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:37)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8130)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8110)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1343)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3781)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3977) 
at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:109) 
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2374) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:233) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:344) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8248) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:589) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1071) 
2023-04-23 20:02:38.050 28492-28492 AndroidRuntime          com.example.myapplication              FATAL EXCEPTION: main